# Magento 1.9.1 configurable swatches, call to a member function

Tags: magento

I hope someone can help me with this bug. I have upgraded to magento 1.9.1, but i cant get the configurable swatches to work. When opening the configurable swatches menu in system/configuration/catalog/configurable swatches i get an exception error.

This is the error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:67:"Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object (boolean)";i:1;s:1399:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/*/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(229): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/*/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(164): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->_initGroup()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/*/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php(93): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initForm()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/*/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(107): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/*/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/*/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/*/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/*/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/*/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/*/httpdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run()
#10 {main}";s:3:"url";s:101:"/index.php/*/system_config/edit/section/configswatches/key/99fc336bef99f324535367aac05a9702/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

I quess there is a mismatch with the database, but i dont have a clue what to do.

regards,

B. van Leenen

Comment: try to reindex magneto..

Answer (score 0):

Magento Configurabe Swatches is developed only for the rwd Package, so make sure that you are using the rwd Package only and recheck the Configurable Color Swatches settings in Magento i.e.

1. Navigate to the System > Configuration > Now click on the Configurable Swatches under Catalog from the left side menu. Check if it is Enable or not and check the other diffrent settings again.
2. Now Navigate to the Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes and check the settings that this attribute is activated for the configurable products or not and other settings as well.
3. Most Important Please keep the image name same as the color name and with the extension .png and put it under the media/wysiwyg/swatches/

Hope it helps,

Thanks